# How to use a variable in Math.floor

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I want to get the max amount of money a person has with

```
let targetUser = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first()) || message.guild.members.get(args[0]);
var targetForMath = userData[targetUser.id].money;
```

and I want to use that variable to set the max amount for a Math.floor. I tried

```
let randomStealCoins = Math.floor(Math.random() * targetForMath) + 1;
```

but when I use that it gives me NaN. How can I make it so it gives me the actual an actual number not something weird?

Comment: Please give some examples of `message` and `userData`.

Comment: message = message in discord userData is a .json that stores data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `targetForMath` is undefined, that will give you `NaN`:
Since:

```
Math.random() * undefined -> NaN
```

I would ensure that targetForMath is a valid number.

Comment: yea I accidentally defined targetForMath after I needed to use it. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not gonna mention that you're mixing `var` and `let`, other than to say that you're doing it and should be careful of that. 
The first question I'd ask is what the `typeof` `userData[targetUser.id].money` is, and more specifically what its *value* is. If it's a number, boolean, `null`, or empty array (?!) it should work, or at least not return NaN. However, if it's a string, undefined, or any other value, JavaScript won't really know what you mean when you say, for example, multiply `Math.random()` times `"fish"`.

Usually in this case it's a good idea to `console.log` out what `userData[targetUser.id]` is, just to make sure the object you're getting back from that is actually what you think it is. Is there actually a property on the `userData` object defined by the `targetUser`'s id?

Comment: At the time I was testing if var or let would work but anyway I fixed it. Thanks for trying to help